# How do I find the general solution of this ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm brand new to differential equations, so when I was given the following equation and told to find the general solution I did this:

$${dy\over dx}=e^x-y$$
$$\int {dy\over dx}dx = \int (e^x-y)dx$$
$$y(x) = e^x - yx + C$$

But I was given three options to choose from:

i. $y(x) = e^x + C$

ii. $y(x) = Ce^{-x}+{1\over 2}e^x$

iii. $y(x) = e^x - {1\over 2}y^2 + C$

My solution isn't there, so what is it that I'm missing?

Comment: If it's multiple choice, you can always just plug all three possible answers into the equation and see which one solves it. However, to properly solve these problems you could use techniques such as integrating factors. Check out this link: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Linear.aspx

Comment: Also, in your approach you integrate $\int -ydx $ as $-yx+c $, however this does not work as $y $ is a function of $x $, and therefore is not treated as a constant when integrating with respect to $x $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y$ depends on $x$, so you can't just integrate it like that. What you actually do to solve this sort of equation (linear in $dy/dx$ and $y$, first-order) is to look for an *integrating factor*, to write the terms involving $y$ as a single derivative that *can* just be integrated. For an equation
$$ \frac{dy}{dx} + p(x)y = q(x), $$
the idea is to rewrite the left-hand side as $ \frac{1}{\mu} \frac{d}{dx}(\mu y) $ for some function $\mu(x)$ (because we know how to integrate $(\mu y)'$). Using the product rule implies that this is equal to $ y'+\frac{\mu'}{\mu}y$, so this will work if
$$ \frac{\mu'}{\mu} = p. $$
This is easy to integrate and we find $\mu(x) = e^{\int p(x) \, dx}$ (there's no need for an arbitrary constant since it cancels when we divide by $\mu$).

---

In this case, $p(x)=1$, so $\mu(x)=e^x$ and the equation becomes
$$ (e^x y)' = e^{2x}. $$
One then integrates once and divides by the integrating factor, which gives
$$ y(x) = Ae^{-x} + \frac{1}{2}e^{x}, $$
where $A$ is a constant arising from the integration. One can check that this satisfies the original equation.